# Change sign up fee cart item price for WooCommerce subscription products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, woocommerce-subscriptions

In WooCommerce I am changing the price of products in cart using the following hooked function:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'set_custom_price',1000,1);
function set_custom_price($cart_obj) {
    foreach ($cart_obj->get_cart() as $key => $value) {
        if($value['alredy_have_number'] == true) {
            $value['data']->set_price(0.90);
        }
    }
}
```

it works fine for recurring price but I wants to change signup fee for subscription products. what function or hook can I use for that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change **some cart item specific metadata** like the **subscription signup fee**, you will use the `WC_Data` method [`update_meta_data()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Data.html#_update_meta_data) that can be used on any `WC_Product` Object like Subscription products.

The related **subscription signup fee** `meta_key` to be used is [`_subscription_sign_up_fee`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/data-structure/#section-4) so in your hooked function code, you will use it this way to change its price:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'change_subscription_data', 1000, 1 );
function change_subscription_data( $cart ) {
    if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX'))
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {

        // Check that product custom cart item data "alredy_have_number" exist and is true
        if( isset($cart_item['alredy_have_number']) && $cart_item['alredy_have_number'] ) {

            // Change subscription price
            $cart_item['data']->set_price(10.60);

            // Only for subscription products
            if ( in_array( $cart_item['data']->get_type(), ['subscription', 'subscription_variation']) ) {
                // Change subscription Sign up fee
                $cart_item['data']->update_meta_data('_subscription_sign_up_fee', 3.40);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: thanks man... this line saved me $cart_item['data']->update_meta_data('_subscription_sign_up_fee', 3.40);